# mixing 2 or more jsonl files together and shuffling them using a bash script

Tags: bash

I have 2 or more jsonl files  files and my objective is to merge the files and shuffle the lines of the output.
The easy case is where I know the number of files and the file names and I can use the command below

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt | shuf
```

However I don't know the number of files in advance. Is there a way so that a script
merge.sh will work on variable number of arguments

```
merge.sh file1.txt file2.txt 
merge.sh file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt
```

Basically I don't know how to use $1 etc when the number of arguments is variable

Comment: You use `"$@"` (with the quotes) to work with "all the parameters", no matter now many there are: `cat "$@" | shuf`

Comment: BTW, don't put `.sh` extensions on scripts; extensions belong on shell _libraries_, not executable commands. (That said, to create a proper executable command, you'll want a shebang on the first line -- like `#!/usr/bin/env bash` -- and executable permissions). It's the same as how Python libraries end with `.py`, but Python scripts in `/bin` don't (you run `pip`, not `pip.py`).